# Why Maggie in True Detective is double-faced?

Tags: character, analysis, true-detective

In *True Detective* Season 1 Episode 6 *Haunted Houses* we see aged Maggie in the interrogation room with Papania and Gilbough. Her face is remarkably asymmetric: the left side is aged, wrinkled and gray while the right side is still young. Also, her hair on the left is dark and her hair on the right is light.
What kind of symbolism is that?

[image: Aged Maggie]

Comment: Is there a picture or a video that shows this more clearly? - because I don't really see it.  Yes her face is asymmetric, particularly the nose and mouth, but I don't see much in the way of differences in wrinkles or hair color that can't be explained by normal differences and shadow.

Comment: I personally don't see the detail either, but to the OP, I  think you've answered your own question, sort of. She's double-faced because she's two-faced. She's lying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are reading into this too much. There is nothing symbolic here. The actress Michelle Monaghan simply has a naturally asymmetric face. I picked three images that I think show this fairly well.

I think that her natural characteristics along with a combination of lighting and makeup make this stand out in the scene you are referring to.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -3):

I have been looking at pictures of myself and I found that the right side of my face looks much older than the left one. I do not have an explanation for this but now I know that some people just look this way. Sorry Michelle Monaghan)